# Pie chart through API call in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display some data in a pie chart that is coming from an API but the problem is that how to apply the JSON data into a pie chart.

Comment: Do you use any package for this?

Comment: Yes I am using **charts_flutter** and for JSON parsing **http**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a custom [json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/16e68w) for this.

**Async function to get data from API**

```
    _getData() async{
    final response = await http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16e68w');
    Map<String,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    return map;
  }
```

Returns json response as a `Map<String, dynamic>`. I didn't parse json.

```
Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
          return new charts.PieChart(
              dataList(snapshot.data),
              defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                  arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator()])
          );
        else
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
  ),
);
```

**Format your data in `charts.Series` list.**

We'll generate a list of LinearSales object for data.

```
    static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> dataList(Map<String, dynamic> apiData) {
      List<LinearSales> list = new List();

      for(int i=0; i<apiData['data'].length; i++)
        list.add(new LinearSales(i, apiData['data'][i]));

      return [
        new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
          id: 'Sales',
          domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
          measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
          data: list,
          labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year}: ${row.sales}',
        )
      ];
    }
  }

class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;
  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Final Result

[image]

Comment: I've updated the answers. Now it gets data from API. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I want full example including **main** method. I am getting problem while debugging.

Comment: here's full code https://gist.github.com/armaansandhu/5d60c4492722b85097f2944e77ddf03b

Comment: **Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')**

Comment: I think you've passed Array instead of Map. Try it with a new flutter project. Just paste the exact code in "main.dart". It's a perfectly working code.

Comment: Make sure to get charts_flutter package

Comment: please do this through this API **http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfwZmvEBbC?indent=2**.And get the index and name of 6 people.Do this in Pie Chart

Comment: Here's the code what you looking for https://gist.github.com/armaansandhu/ff542071a600c14665150f605fef9dc3 

There is no data for PieChart in your API and Your API is returning List of JSON objects. The above answer is an appropriate answer to your question. Please accept this answer for this question.

Comment: I want data from 4 APIs and then place them in a list and then use that list to draw the pie chart.

Comment: I am really strucked at this point and want a full example for the same to understand it completely.

Comment: can anyone do this by using bloc pattern and stream builder

Comment: Very helpful.  Most of the posts/examples I've seen on charts_flutter use hard-coded lists of sample data and don't deal with the async/future part.  This got me pointed in the right direction.