# How to display pie chart with json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, charts, line

i'm still new to flutter and I've been trying to display some data from a http request in a pie-chart. I couldn't find any example for this.
I have been searching the internet for three days now and there is no complete example
I hope of you  help me :)

I worked on these two solutions but the json files  of both examples were not visible and I could not succeed    [Pie chart through API call in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830360/pie-chart-through-api-call-in-flutter)  and    [How to display json data in flutter charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349936/how-to-display-json-data-in-flutter-charts)

Comment: There isn't a lot you are providing us in the question. Edit the question to show up what you've tried, an example of the JSON data, etc.

Comment: I worked on these two solutions but the json files  of both examples were not visible and I could not succeed    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830360/pie-chart-through-api-call-in-flutter  and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349936/how-to-display-json-data-in-flutter-charts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pie_chart`](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart) to create a simple pie chart.

You can implement it like this:

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final Map<String, double> sampleData = {
  "Flutter": 5,
  "React": 3,
  "Xamarin": 2,
  "Ionic": 2,
};

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: PieChartView(
        jsonData: sampleData,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PieChartView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PieChartView({this.jsonData});

  final Map<String, double> jsonData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: PieChart(dataMap: jsonData));
  }
}
```

[image: Pie chart example]

Comment: Thank you very much ser Apealed for helping me , 
Can I draw a bar chart the same way?

Comment: Not with this package, no. You will need a another package like [`flutter_charts`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_charts) to achieve this. I recommend looking into their [example app](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_charts/example) to see if they have anything immediately helpful.